# How to append query response which is as object using foreach in node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, foreach

I am building one API which will trigger a sql query and then some attribute of query result (which can have multiple rows) will be appended into existing resultschema.js

Structure of my object is:

```
[ { id: 1,
    code: 'CODTN',
    name: 'Condition',
    ver: '1'},
  { id: 2,
    code: 'POLICY',
    name: 'Policy',
    ver: '1' }
]
```

From above result I want to append 'id' and 'name' into one of the array using foreach.

myapp.js:

```
let Object=require('../schema/resultschema')

var newArray = []

try{

        Objectdetail.forEach(function(items){
        Object.Class.properties.id=items.id
        Object.Class.properties.code=items.code
        Object.Class.properties.name=items.name
        Object.Class.properties.ver=items.ver

        newArray.push(Object.Class.properties)

    })
```

resultschema.js

```
let Object={    
    Class: {
      properties:{
        id: "",
        code: "",
        name: "",
        ver: ""
      }
      }}
```

Note: Output is coming as Object and not in Json format.

Comment: show the output and your code in which you are appending these two fields!

Comment: can you add some more code? Your question doesn't have enough information

Comment: @AkifHussain here is some code:

myapp.js:

```
let Object=require('../schema/resultschema')
var newArray = []
try{
        Objectdetail.forEach(function(items){
        Object.Class.properties.id=items.id
        Object.Class.properties.code=items.code
        Object.Class.properties.name=items.name
        Object.Class.properties.ver=items.ver
        newArray.push(Object.Class.properties)
    })
```
 
resultschema.js

```
let Object={    
 Class: {
      properties:{
        id: "",
        code: "",
        name: "",
        ver: ""
      }
      }}
```

Comment: Would you mind to edit the question?
Moreover, you are using a JSON, overwriting the default `Object` class

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon You can now refer latest question. Thank You !